# How to access CloudFront Cache Statistics via SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to access the Cloudfront Cache Statistics programmatically. Via the UI you can see the Statistics via clicking on "CloudFront" and then on the left side under "Reports & analytics" the link "Cache Statistics".

I am using the Java SDK 1.11. However the structure is similar in all sdk bindings. I already tried:

```
    AmazonCloudFront cloudFront = AmazonCloudFrontClientBuilder.defaultClient();

    GetDistributionRequest request = new GetDistributionRequest();
    request.setId("E3C1N6KKRS04QE");

    GetDistributionResult result = cloudFront.getDistribution(request);
    System.out.println(result);
```

However, that seems to get my the information shown on the "Distribution"-Tab in the UI. Any help would be appreciated!